# PHP How to show search results like search engine

Tags: php, mysql, regex, search, replace

I have a search page in my website.
I don't want to show the entire sentence in the results, I would like to show it in "Google style":
5 characters before, **searched word highlighted**, 5 characters after...
and so on, for every word found in the sentence.

```
$teksto="bla1 bla2 bla3 bla4 bla5 Bingo bla6 bla7 bla8 bla9 bla10 Bingo bla11 bla12 Bingo bla13 bla14 bla15";
$serchu="bingo";
$teksto=preg_replace("/[\s]{1,}/is",' ',$teksto); // (form multispaces, breaklines, etc. to just 1 space)
echo preg_replace("/(.{0,5})($serchu)(.{0,5})/is"," ...$1<b>$2</b>$3... &nbsp;&nbsp;",$texto);
```

The result is:
bla1 bla2 bla3 bla4 ...bla5 **Bingo** bla6...    ***bla7 bla8 bla9 b*** ...la10 **Bingo** bla1...   ***1 b*** ...la12 **Bingo** bla1...   3 bla14 bla15

I would like the result could be:
...bla5 **Bingo** bla6...   ...la10 **Bingo** bla1...   ...la12 **Bingo** bla1...

In other words, i don't want ***the other words***, at the beginning or end.
MySQL solution also appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that you use a dot for a word. The dot stands for a single character. Acutally the result of your pattern is the 5 precedent characters, the keyword highlighted and 5 characters  after. You need to make a better description of the words before and after the keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing things, try to match only the matched word and print some context around it. This searches for all occurrences of `$serchu`, with 5 chars before and after it, and puts the result together with "..." between it:

```
preg_match_all("/.....$serchu...../i", $teksto, $matches);
echo implode('...', $matches[0]);
```

Result:

```
 bla5 Bingo bla6...la10 Bingo bla1...la12 Bingo bla1
```

This does not work when `$serchu` is just at the beginning or end of the string, but I think you will have more success fixing this aproach than with the `preg_replace`.

Comment: Why not `.{0,5}` instead of `.....`? Makes it much more readable/maintainable :)

Comment: I think that the OP want five "words" instead of five characters.

Comment: @Casimir nono: five characters (to make the question more readable).
In the practice I will use a little bit more. (By the way, split in words seems a nice suggestion!)

Comment: Thank you very much!
It works very fine!
_With **.{0,5}** clause, I can show also if **$teksto** is at the begin of the sentence_

`preg_match_all("/.{0,5}$q.{0,5}/is",$teksto,$matches);`
`echo preg_replace("/($serchu)/is"," <b>$1</b>",implode('... &nbsp;', $matches[0]));`